# How to quickly familiarize yourself with the usage of a python third party Library

Tags: python

When learning python, I have a puzzle. Python has rich third-party libraries, but it makes me a novice difficult to use them. For example, when using Matplotlib, I just know what it can do, but specifically, for example, I want to draw a complex diagram, but I can't start with it, because there are many functions, but I don't know where they are, The introduction of the official manual sometimes feels a little abstract. If you go to Google and search a specific function, you may not get the desired result. So how do you quickly start a third-party library

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.  You're asking us how to do research, and you want us to teach you how *you* will learn best.  This is not a Stack Overflow matter.

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways to get familiarised quickly with any 3rd party lib (python lib) is to go through getting started / Quickstart section of the documentation (for any library)

If that doesn't help then these two below sites have always helped me get a quick intro and basic hands-on for most of python libs

1. Real Python (https://realpython.com)
2. Tutorialspoint (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/index.htm)
3. Full-stack Python (https://www.fullstackpython.com) is another site I refer to when I have to find a new python library.

These sites pretty much cover almost all the well known python libraries.

And most of the famous libraries documentation sites provide a link to some sort of community on discord / Gitter  / some site which would help further.

Example: Numpy
[Learn section with Quickstart and other example based tuts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpMEV.png)
[community section with links to several groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAUlD.png)